# Non-blocking version of Popen.communicate() in Python Subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to execute multiple commands in parallel in two shells spawned in a Python program. I've tried to use popen.communicate(), however this method is blocking and does not allow me to run them simultaneously. I currently have.

```
proc_1 = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc_2 = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc_1.communicate(b'second adb command')
proc_2.communicate(b'second adb command')
```

It's currently waiting for the first communicate call to finish before proceeding to the second. How could I run them both in parallel?

Comment: Python multiprocessing module will be a suitable choice.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago, Is it possible to use `multiprocessing` to run non-python programs?

Comment: @azelcer Yes you can run it and pass arguments. Take a look at this page which guides you to run a process out of python: "https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class"

Answer (score 1):

This is the [expected behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) of `communicate`

> Read data from `stdout` and `stderr`, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate and set the `returncode` attribute.

Since you do not need to manage `stdout` nor `stderr`, it *should be* enough to call `communicate` with a timeout of `0` and catch the `TimeoutExpired` exception:

```py
import subprocess

def communicate_nowait(proc, message):
    try:
        proc.communicate(message, 1E-3)  # 0 might have problems
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        pass
    
proc_1 = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc_2 = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
communicate_nowait(proc_1, b'second adb command')
communicate_nowait(proc_2, b'second adb command')
```

Please note that you will have to take care of cleanup properly (refer to `communicate` documentation).

**Warning**:
It seems that a too small timeout might cause problems (see [reported bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue29472)).